# Flatpak автозапуск qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, flatpak

Есть программа в Qt C++. Нужно сделать настройку автозапуска: поставили галку в чекбокс - работает автозапуск; нет - соответственно, не работает. С виндой всё понятно, проблема с flatpak. Код ниже (добавлена только самая важная часть). Проблема, что .desktop файл создаётся НЕ в ~/.config/autostart! Он создаётся в .var/app/com.../config/autostart. Соответственно, автозапуск не работает(( Как сделать автозапуск для флатпака? Надо как-то заставить flatpak (*забыть свои принципы*) создать файл в нужной директории? Решения типа командой строки/Flatseal не подходят(( Нужно закодить

```
    QString autostartPath =
QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation).at(0) + QLatin1String("/autostart");
QDir autostartDir(autostartPath);

if (!autostartDir.exists()) {
autostartDir.mkpath(autostartPath);
}

 QFile autostartFile(autostartPath + R"(/MyAppName.desktop)");

QTextStream stream(&autostartFile);
stream << "[Desktop Entry]\n"
      "Type=Application\n" +
          "Exec=flatpak run" + value  +
          "Name=MyAppName\n"
...... и т.д.
```

Comment: делай чтоб создавался в $HOME/.config/autostart